# Display recent categories Wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having trouble with a widget that displays the most recent categories.

Code: <s>https://ghostbin.com/paste/6cwa5</s> https://ghostbin.com/paste/rtnqa

It is displaying fine on the main page but when I go to a post page, it only shows that pages' categories.

Also, I have to force the widget to close with the `aside` tag.

What am I doing wrong? Should I not be using the `wp_get_recent_posts` function?

Why doesn't `array_key_exists('after_widget', $args)` return true using twelvefifteen theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `wp_get_recents_posts`? As far as I can see from a quick look it´s not really different to `get_posts()` with standard values at all.

Besides that your lines 91 and 92 could be the troublemaker.

```
foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
```

I think, `$post` is really bound to the current post you are looking at. That is no big thing on the homepage, but once you view an article, your loop-$post could be overwritten by the blogpost-$post (you know what I mean?).

Try changing those to something different than `$post`, that might solve your problem.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of the `$post` problem. This seemed to have fixed most of my problems when switching to `get_posts()`. Any idea for the closing tag? I've updated my code.

Comment: I had a look at that and find it quite curious. Actually I never had to set the closing aside by myself, WordPress (or the theme) handled that for me. Are you using a bought theme or something you developed yourself?

Comment: Using the twenty fifteen theme (default)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
```

insteadof you can use, this one belown.

because $post is a global varaiable.

Example:

```
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

    foreach ($categories as $cat) {

        echo $cat->cat_name;
    }
```

Comment: I think something is missing after the "instead you can use" line